# C++ different instance of class

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to C++ so I'm not exactly sure what to put into the title of this problem. Anyway, I created a class whose purpose is to create a Label then use it later to create another Label again and again.

```
CALLBACK MyClassName::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept -> LRESULT {
   ....
        switch (msg) {
    ....
        case WM_CREATE:
        {  
            ControlLabel controlLabel, anotherLabel; //declare two control label
            
            controlLabel.Label(123, hwnd);          //Set new id and window handle for label
            controlLabel.SetXPosition(68);          //Set x position
            controlLabel.SetYPosition(110);         //Set y position
            controlLabel.SetText("This is Label");  //Set the text of Label
            controlLabel.SetFontSize(14);           //Set the font size of the text


            anotherLabel.Label(456, hwnd);          //Create and set new id and window handle for another label
            anotherLabel.SetXPosition(68);          //Set x position of another label
            anotherLabel.SetYPosition(140);         //Set y position of another label
            anotherLabel.SetText("This is another Label");  //Set the text of another label
            anotherLabel.SetFontSize(14);           //Set the font size of another label

            break;
        }
        ....
    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

I'm expecting it to have an output of two different labels, e.g.

> This is Label 
> This is another Label

Instead, I get two Labels with the same text.

> This is another Label 
> This is another Label

Anyway, here's the full source of the class.

**ControlLabel.H**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CONTROLLABEL_H
#define CONTROLLABEL_H
#include "Header.h"

class ControlLabel {

public:
    ControlLabel();
    HWND Label(int Label_ID, HWND WindowHandle);
    void SetXPosition(int xPosition);
    void SetYPosition(int yPosition);
    void SetText(string Text);
    void SetFontFamily(string FontFamily);
    void SetFontSize(int FontSize);
    void SetFontColor(int R, int G, int B);
    void SetBackgroundColor(int Rr, int Gg, int Bb, bool SetBGColor);

private:
    void UpdateLabel();
    void SetWidthAndHeights();
    static std::wstring StringConverter(const std::string& s);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK LabelProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
    static HWND LabelHandle;
    static SolidBrush vFontColor;
    static string text, vFontFamily;
    static bool SetBGColor;
    static int xPosition, yPosition, width, height, LABEL_ID, vFontSize, R, G, B, BckR, BckG, BckB;
};

#endif
```

**ControlLabel.cpp**

```
#include "ControlLabel.h"

HWND ControlLabel::LabelHandle = NULL;
int ControlLabel::xPosition = 0;
int ControlLabel::yPosition = 0;
int ControlLabel::width = 0;
int ControlLabel::height = 0;
int ControlLabel::LABEL_ID = 0;
int ControlLabel::vFontSize = 12;
int ControlLabel::R = 0;
int ControlLabel::G = 0;
int ControlLabel::B = 0;
int ControlLabel::BckR = 0;
int ControlLabel::BckG = 0;
int ControlLabel::BckB = 0;
bool ControlLabel::SetBGColor = FALSE;
string ControlLabel::text = "Label";
string ControlLabel::vFontFamily = "Segoe UI";

ControlLabel::ControlLabel() {}

/** This function is used to convert string into std::wstring. **/
std::wstring ControlLabel::StringConverter(const std::string& s) {
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

/** This function is used to automatically set the Width and Height of static control base on the length of the text. **/
void ControlLabel::SetWidthAndHeights() {    
    std::wstring fontFamilyTemp = StringConverter(vFontFamily);
    std::wstring  textTemp = StringConverter(text);
    LPCWSTR textLabel = textTemp.c_str();

    HDC hdc = GetDC(LabelHandle);//static control
    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(
          -MulDiv(vFontSize, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX), 90), //calculate the actual cHeight.
          0, 0, 0, // normal orientation
          FW_NORMAL,   // normal weight--e.g., bold would be FW_BOLD
          false, false, false, // not italic, underlined or strike out
          DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, // select only outline (not bitmap) fonts
          CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH | FF_SWISS, fontFamilyTemp.c_str());

    SIZE size;
    HFONT oldfont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
    GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, textLabel, wcslen(textLabel), &size);
    width = size.cx;
    height = size.cy;

    SelectObject(hdc, oldfont); //don't forget to select the old.
    DeleteObject(hFont); //always delete the object after creating it.
    ReleaseDC(LabelHandle, hdc); //alway reelase dc after using.

    /*char buffer[100];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "WIDTH: %d | HEIGHT: %d\n", width, height);
    OutputDebugStringA(buffer);*/
}

/** This function will be called when new option is set. For example, fontSize is set. **/
void ControlLabel::UpdateLabel() {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        SetWidthAndHeights();
        SetWindowPos(LabelHandle, nullptr, xPosition, yPosition, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        InvalidateRect(LabelHandle, NULL, FALSE);
        UpdateWindow(LabelHandle);
    }
}

/** This is the callback function of static control. **/
LRESULT CALLBACK ControlLabel::LabelProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch(uMsg) {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            if(SetBGColor) { //We only want to do this if the SetColor is modified to true, meaning we want to set the color of background.
                RECT rect;
                GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
                FillRect((HDC)wParam, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(BckR, BckG, BckB))); //set titlebar background color.
                return 1; //return 1, meaning we take care of erasing the background.
            }
            return 0;
        }case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            Graphics g(hdc);

            std::wstring fontFamilyTemp = StringConverter(vFontFamily);
            std::wstring  textTemp = StringConverter(text);

            FontFamily  theFontFamily(fontFamilyTemp.c_str());
            Font        font(&theFontFamily, vFontSize, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
            SolidBrush  brush(Color(255, R, G, B));
            PointF      pointF(0.0f, 0.0f);

            TextRenderingHint hint = g.GetTextRenderingHint(); // Get the text rendering hint.
            g.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias); // Set the text rendering hint to TextRenderingHintAntiAlias. 
            g.DrawString(textTemp.c_str(), -1, &font, pointF, &brush); 

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return TRUE;
        }case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, LabelProc, uIdSubclass);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

/** Use this function to create a Label. Parent or WindowHandle must be specified, this is where the Label will be drawn. Unique Label ID must be specified. **/
HWND ControlLabel::Label(int Label_ID, HWND WindowHandle) {
    LABEL_ID = Label_ID;
    LabelHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_OWNERDRAW, xPosition, yPosition, width, height, WindowHandle, NULL, NULL, NULL); //create the static control.
    SetWindowSubclass(LabelHandle, &LabelProc, LABEL_ID, 0);
    return LabelHandle;
}

/** Use this function to set the X Position of the Label. **/
void ControlLabel::SetXPosition(int xxPosition) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        xPosition = xxPosition; //set xposition
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this function to set the Y Position of the Label. **/
void ControlLabel::SetYPosition(int yyPosition) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        yPosition = yyPosition; //set xposition
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this function to set the text of the Label. **/
void ControlLabel::SetText(string ttext) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        text = ttext; //set text
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this function to set the font family of the Label. **/
void ControlLabel::SetFontFamily(string font_family) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        vFontFamily = font_family; //set font family
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this function to set the font size of the Label. **/
void ControlLabel::SetFontSize(int size) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        vFontSize = size; //set font size
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this Function to set the font color of the Label using RGB. **/
void ControlLabel::SetFontColor(int Rr, int Gg, int Bb) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        R = Rr; 
        G = Gg; 
        B = Bb; 
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}

/** Use this Function to set the background color of the Label using RGB. Last parameter must be TRUE if you want to set your own background color. **/
void ControlLabel::SetBackgroundColor(int Rr, int Gg, int Bb, bool setColor) {
    if(LabelHandle != NULL) {
        SetBGColor = setColor;
        BckR = Rr;
        BckG = Gg;
        BckB = Bb;
        UpdateLabel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Static class members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) are shared between all instances of a class. There's a `static string text` in your class so it is to be expected that all instances share that. If you need to store per-instance data you need to use non-static class members.

Presumably, you've used static class members so that you can put your window procedure inside the class' implementation (which needs to be static). To have a static window procedure access per-instance data has been asked and answered before (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21369256/1889329), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14661865/1889329), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34009967/1889329), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29039137/1889329)).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "instance" when all your variables are declared `static`. `static` means the variable is shared among all instances of the class, making it essentially global. So, when you call:

```
controlLabel.SetText("This is Label");
```

You assign your text to the global `text` variable. Then, calling

```
anotherLabel.SetText("This is another Label");
```

Assigns the new string to that same global `text` variable. Your original string was forgotten at this point.

How can you solve this? I can think of multiple ways off the top of my head, maybe you can think of something better. The idea is to somehow bind the text (or the entire `controlLabel` instance) to a label.

- Putting the label text directly into the window data (using `WM_SETTEXT`. Then you can pull it up in `LabelProc` and draw it, or just let the default `STATIC` window procedure handle it.
- Making the labels a custom window class that has some extra space reserved for each window instance. Then use `SetWindowLong` to put a pointer to a whole `controlLabel` in there. Raw pointers are generally not a great thing in C++, but then again, Win32 API was made for C. Then pull the instance up when needed with `GetWindowLong`. Just remember to un-`static` the `text` member, so it doesn't get overwritten.
- Use a global/static `std::map<HWND, controlLabel>` to associate each label with an instance of `controlLabel`. Again, if you do this, remember to un-`static` the `text`.

Oh, and when you called any `controlLabel` method that somehow uses the label handle, you just randomly happened to have the handle that you wanted in the `LabelHandle` variable, since it's also `static`.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense, you won't be able to have a different instance if all your members are static.

However, since the callback of window procedure needs to be static, then you won't be able to access those non-static members inside that function.

What you can do is use the `dwRefData` parameter of the subclass to pass the instance of your class into your callback function. You can then cast that parameter to access non-static members.

For example in your `::Label` function;

```
SetWindowSubclass(LabelHandle, &LabelProc, LABEL_ID, <DWORD_PTR>(this)); //notice the last parameter, pass `this` instance so you can use `dwRefData`.
```

Then on your callback;

```
ControlLabel* controlLabel = reinterpret_cast<ControlLabel*>(dwRefData); //type cast the value of dwRefData.
controlLabel->text //you can now access your non-static variable text
controlLabel->vFontFamily //you can now access your non-static variable vFontFamily
```

Something like that.

Another problem is you shouldn't declare your callback as private, make it public instead. And do not declare your `ControlLabel` object inside the `WM_CREATE`, make it global instead.

```
ControlLabel controlLabel, anotherLabel; //declare two control label as Global.

CALLBACK MyClassName::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept -> LRESULT {
   ....
        switch (msg) {
    ....
        case WM_CREATE:
        {  
            controlLabel.Label(123, hwnd);          //Set new id and window handle for label
            ...
            anotherLabel.Label(456, hwnd);          //Create and set new id and window handle for another label
            ...
            break;
        }
        ....
    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Anyway, I noticed your class doesn't have destructor to destroy your `LabelHandle`. Make sure to do that.

```
ControlLabel.h   //In your ControlLabel.h
~ControlLabel(); //should be in public

ControlLabel.cpp  //In your ControlLabel.cpp
ControlLabel::~ControlLabel() {
    if(LabelHandle) DestroyWindow(LabelHandle); //destroy when done.
}
```